# What is the syntax to make Host group a variable in "when inventory_hostname"?

Tags: ansible

I recently discovered how use "when inventory_hostname" to set_fact for the first host in an host group.  I was wondering how to pass a variable as the host group. In my testing I use the following:

Inventory file:

```
---
[test]
test-001.example.com
test-002.example.com
```

vars file:

```
---
declared_hostgroup: test
```

playbook:

```
- name: set first host in group as master
  set_fact:
    test_order: MASTER
  when: inventory_hostname == group.test[0]
```

That works great.  But I would like to replace "test" in "group.test" with the variable "declared_hostgroup". I've tried {{ }} syntax with no success.  Any suggestions would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the correct syntax:

```
when: inventory_hostname == group[declared_hostgroup][0]
```

But keep in mind that although Ansible tries to keep order of host consistent, it can break sometime in the future (e.g. different sort order or some other quirks), so you may want to mark your host inside inventory for clarity.